# Jetpack Compose Preview doesn't work with resources after changing a branch in git

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a strange problem with the preview of compose. Recently I've added compose to my project. Everything works well unless I switch to an older branch without compose. After changing back to the compose branch the preview stops working. Restart / Invalidate / Rebuild doesn't help. The code runs on an emulator well.
I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox Stable with Compose 1.0.0
Here are the dependencies:

```
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
```

For example, the following code has a rendering problem:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMyScreen(){
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_android_24dp), contentDescription = null)
}
```

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F08006C.
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1153)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1129)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1133)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getResourceValue(Resources_Delegate.java:921)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:892)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1428)
    at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:60)
    at com.roysolberg.android.datacounter.fragment.AppUsageDetailsNewActivityKt.PreviewMyScreen(AppUsageDetailsNewActivity.kt:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:149)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:188)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:553)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:551)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:590)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:546)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:495)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:494)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:490)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:546)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:543)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3330)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:814)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Update**
Suddenly everything started working after changing the preview a few times with different models. Looks some bug with caching

Comment: Please re-check the resource directory for the availability to the desired resource

Comment: @MARSK It has the resource. Looks like something with the cache of privew.

Comment: I got the same problem with my app, but Google's demo app works fine.

Comment: @metaleater same here =(

Answer (score -2):

`import com.package.R`

Of course, replace the 'project' with the actual name.

Comment: As I said. The code compiles and works on the emulator. Of course, it has the needed import to the R.

Comment: The project would compile even if you did not import this `R`. There are two of them. One from the Android package and one specific to your package. I wanted to say, that you import the right one

Comment: Ok. Now it's clear. But it isn't the case. There import is correct